# absolute image positioning

Tags: graphics, positioning

I've the following code where I'm trying to align the photo to the right, like resume with top right aligned photo. However this is what I get, no matter what I tried I couldn't position the image to the right! it just sits in the middle.

[image: result]

[image]

```
% LaTeX resume using res.cls
\documentclass[margin]{res}
%\usepackage{helvetica} % uses helvetica postscript font (download helvetica.sty)
%\usepackage{newcent}   % uses new century schoolbook postscript font 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.1in} % set width of text portion
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}% adapt widths of minipages to your needs


\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{\large\bf Eralp B}
% \includegraphics[]{photo.jpg}
\moveleft\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width\resumewidth height 1pt}\smallskip

\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{my address}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
\begin{scope}[shift={(-5,20)}]
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{ata.jpg}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
```

If you need the res.cls, it's here: https://justpaste.it/7e2gh

Comment: Could you please add a description on how/where you want your image to be exactly? Shoild it be aligned with the right margin or the right end of the page? Should it overlap the horizontal line?...

Comment: @leandriis I updated my question to reflect this, some margin from the right, and it can be centered on the line or on the whole minipage, I don't need it to be pixel perfect, any common sense positioning would be fine :)

Comment: If you are willing to use a tikzpicture, check out tikzpgenodes.